# POS tagging - NLTK- Python

Tags: python, nltk

I want to use `word_tokenize, pos_tag, FreqDist`. I don't want to download all `nltk` as default. I want to use `nltk.download(info_or_id='')`. What options I should put in `info_or_id` to get the POS tagging and its frequency. POS tagging - Penn Treebank POS.

Comment: what do you mean by "_POS tagging - Penn Treebank POS_"?

Comment: He means Part Of Speech - analyzing text sentences for e.g. verb/noun/adverb. It's one of the functions of the Python NLTK (Natural Language Tool Kit, before you ask)  http://www.nltk.org/.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the corpora http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/ each description includes its id, e.g. brown, wordnet, book_grammars. Which you choose is up to you, depends on your application. Look for a tagged corpora, e.g. Brown include POS, you'll have to look at each one, I guess, to see. Treebank mentions Penn Treebank (id treebank), also Sinica Treebank (id sinica_treebank). See below heading Parsed Corpora here http://www.nltk.org/howto/corpus.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question confuses the `nltk` itself with `nltk_data`. You can't really download just part of the nltk (though you could manually trim it down, carefully, if you need to save space). But I think you're trying to avoid downloading all of the nltk data. As @barny wrote, you can see the IDs of different resources when you open the interactive `nltk.download()` window.

1. To use the treebank pos tagger, you need its pickled training tables (*not* the treebank corpus); you'll find them in the "Models" tab under the ID `maxent_treebank_pos_tagger`. (Hence: `nltk.download("maxent_treebank_pos_tagger")`.
2. The `FreqDist` class doesn't have or need any trained model.
3. Neither does `word_tokenize`, which takes a sentence as a single string and breaks it up into words. However, you'll probably need the model for `sent_tokenize`, which breaks up a longer text into sentences. That's handled by the "Punkt" sentence tokenizer, and you can download its model with `nltk.download("punkt")`.

PS. For general-purpose use, I recommend downloading everything in the "book" collection, i.e. `nltk.download("book")`. It's only a fraction of the total, and it lets you do most things without scrambling every so often to figure out what's missing.